# cx_Freeze while creating an executable not ecognizing JIRA

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze, python-jira

I am creating an executable using python 'cx_Freeze' module. Though I have jira packages installed, I am getting the following error:

```
   C:\Users\shanmuganandhavadive\PycharmProjects\Jira_tool\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7>jira_auto_ticket_creation_UI.exe
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\shanmuganandhavadive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 442, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
   provider = pkg_resources.get_provider(requirement)
   File "C:\Users\shanmuganandhavadive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 357, in get_provider
   return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
   File "C:\Users\shanmuganandhavadive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 900, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
   File "C:\Users\shanmuganandhavadive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
   raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
   pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jira' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I have already read the post here:
[I created a python executable by using pyinstaller, but the module imported to my .py script is not present when I execute executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838701/i-created-a-python-executable-by-using-pyinstaller-but-the-module-imported-to-m)

But it is not helping much to do the same for cx_Freeze. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I included the missing package via `include_files` and solved the problem.

Reference: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/438#issuecomment-472954154